# Proving an identity (differential geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I'm trying to prove that
$$ \nabla_c\nabla_bu^a - \nabla_b\nabla_cu^a = -R^a_{dbc}u^d-2\Gamma^d_{[bc]}\nabla_du^a $$
My calculations:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\require{cancel}
\nabla_c\nabla_bu^a - \nabla_b\nabla_cu^a &= \nabla_c( \partial_b u^a + \Gamma^a_{b d}u^d ) - \nabla_b( \partial_c u^a + \Gamma^a_{c d}u^d ) \\
&= \nabla_c(\partial_b u^a) + \nabla_c(\Gamma^a_{b d}u^d ) - \nabla_b( \partial_c u^a ) - \nabla_b(\Gamma^a_{c d}u^d ) \\
&= \cancel{\partial_c\partial_bu^a} - \Gamma^e_{bc}\partial_eu^a + \bcancel{\Gamma^a_{ce}\partial_bu^e} + (\partial_c\Gamma^a_{bd})u^d + \xcancel{\Gamma^a_{bd}\partial_cu^d} + \Gamma^a_{bd}\Gamma^d_{ce}u^e \\
&- \cancel{\partial_b\partial_cu^a} + \Gamma^e_{cb}\partial_eu^a - \xcancel{\Gamma^a_{be}\partial_cu^e} - (\partial_b\Gamma^a_{cd})u^d - \bcancel{\Gamma^a_{cd}\partial_bu^d} - \Gamma^a_{cd}\Gamma^d_{be}u^e \\
&= (\partial_c\Gamma^a_{bd} - \partial_b\Gamma^a_{cd} + \Gamma^a_{be}\Gamma^e_{cd} - \Gamma^a_{ce}\Gamma^e_{bd})u^d + 2 \frac{1}{2}(\Gamma^d_{cb} - \Gamma^d_{bc})(\partial_du^a) \\
&= (\partial_c\Gamma^a_{bd} - \partial_b\Gamma^a_{cd} + \Gamma^a_{be}\Gamma^e_{cd} - \Gamma^a_{ce}\Gamma^e_{bd})u^d + 2 \Gamma^d_{[cb]}(\partial_du^a)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

There's clearly a missing term (probably a silly mistake). I need some help to pinpoint the mistake.

Comment: Why is there only $a,b$ and $c$ indices on the LHS but a non-dummy $d$ on the RHS (in $R^a_{dbc})$?

Comment: @Didier You're right, i corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake. $\partial_bu^a$ is not a tensor and so $\nabla_c(\partial_bu^a) \ne \partial_c\partial_bu^a - \Gamma^e_{bc}\partial_eu^a + \Gamma^a_{ce}\partial_bu^e$. To find the correct expression you need to find the covariant derivative of $\nabla_bu^a$ which is a tensor.